# What is the density of co-prime numbers.

Tags: number-theory

If you were to graph all the integer points on the x-y planes, and then color all the points where x and y create an simplest fraction red, and the rest blue, what is the average density of red points if you look around the point of (a,b). What can we say about the points next to another point in terms of co-primeness.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers#Probability_of_coprimality) gives it as $\frac 6{\pi^2} \approx 0.6079$

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers#Probability_of_coprimality